# Setting attribute on an sqlachemy instance breaks Mapping

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mapping

I have a class that inherits from `collections.Mapping` and in the same time is mapped with `sqlalchemy.orm.mapper`. I do this for the convenience of

```
'{some_attribute}-{of}-{the}-{instance}'.format(**instance)
```

and it works fine until I change some attributes after getting an instance from DB:

```
setattr(instance, 'some_attribute', 'some_value')
'{some_attribute}-{of}-{the}-{instance}'.format(**instance)
```

Now I get: `TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not InstanceClass`.

What am I missing here? Some special behavior of sqlalchemy-mapped instance?